# Python (Pycharm): [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to read a CSV file with Pandas. However I get the following error:

```
C:\Python\python.exe "C:/Users/Niels Hoogeveen/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py"
C:\Python\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/Niels Hoogeveen/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried the absolute path, but I get the same error time and time again.
See the screenshot below.

What do I need to do?

[screenshot of my code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1G2o.png)

Comment: you don't have any script called "HelloWorld.py", but "test.py".

Answer (score 1):

Your file is called **test.py** instead of **HelloWorld.py**

By the way, it's possible that **'/'** must be replaced by **'\'**

Answer (score 0):

Your Python file's name is not HelloWorld.py, it is test.py. :) Just change the name in the PyCharm terminal and it should start to work.